# Adding a grid (like a background image) to one html element

Tags: css, canvas, background, grid

I want to add a grid in a canvas class, which supposed to look like a background image (actually a table) of this canvas (see below). I could add a div container below the canvas element, style it like a table and shift it in the background of the canvas. But I was wondering if I can add a grid like http://www.linker.ch/graf/sudoku/sudoku_vorlage.GIF directly via css by referencing only the canvas element. For example with before, after?

```
 <canvas class="sigma-mouse" width="964" height="602px" style="position: absolute; width: 964px; height: 602px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: You want something like this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/

Comment: yes, that's great, but how can I bind this in my canvas? Is it correct, that I have a jss-file in my directory? But where do I type the html- and css-code? Sorry for this question, I'm a newbie.

Comment: http://enterprisebug.github.io/grid.js/  take a look